# magnetic Disk Calculation

Tags: mathematical-foundations, filesystems

A magnetic disk has `1000 cylinders`, `10 tracks per cylinder`, `128 sectors per track`, `1 KB per sector`. The `rotation time is 6 msec`, `maximum seek time is 150 msec`, `switching between adjacent cylinders takes 15 msec`, and switching between adjacent tracks within a cylinder takes no time. Assume this `disk has 4 MB` of data stored on it.If data is stored on consecutive tracks and is twice as likely to start on the first half (upper 5 tracks) of a cylinder than the second half (lower 5 tracks), find the average access time

**Solution**'

```
#Tracks: 4 MB x 1024 KB/1 MB x 1 sector/1 KB x 1 track/128 sectors = 32 tracks 
Transfer time = 32 x 6 = 192 msec

Exp. switch and wait: Probability (twice as likely) -> If x = probability, 
5 x 2x + 5 x 1x = 1 -> x = 1/15

         Track  Probability   # switch s/w time
           1     2/15               3               18x3 
           2     2/15               3               18x3
           3     2/15               3               18x3
           4     2/15               3               18x3
           5     2/15               3               18x3
           6     1/15               3               18x3
           7     1/15               3               18x3
           8     1/15               3               18x3
           9     1/15               3               18x3
          10     1/15               4               18x4

        Exp. s/w = 5 x [(18x3) x 2/15] + 4 x [(18x3) x 1/15] + [(18x4) x 1/15] = 55.2 msec

        Exp. access time = exp seek + exp latency + transfer + exp s/w = (1/3 x 150) + (1/2 x 6) + 192 + 55.2
                = 300.2 msec
```

Is there a easier method to this question maybe with formulas or something,

Comment: This seems to be about basic arithmetics, not computer science.

Comment: i posted it in a math forum they directed me here

Comment: They were wrong; not everything about computers is computer *science*. If you want to calculate how far you get with 10l of gas you don't ask the mechanical engineer who constructed your car, or do you?

Comment: m tired of jumping from one forum to another :(

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76106/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294211/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you are frustrated and feel like you're getting the run-around.  I understand.  However, we have our own community standards to maintain.  Please understand that we can't control what someone else on some other site might suggest -- and, assuming they're not a member of this community, it's not really their place to say what is suitable here and what is not.  It's possible that they may have just been trying to help, without really understanding what our scope or standards are.